# how to replace date format in a dynamic string variable?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match

my variable is a dynamic string variable in this string i have some date value and looks like

```
$var = 'bd','100','10-05-2013','20-05-2013','alise';
```

but i want to change this date format like

```
$var = 'bd','100','2013-05-10','2013-05-20','alise';
```

my variable is dynamic so date position and number of dates not fixed.

Thanks

Comment: How are you building the string? It's probably more reliable to set the date format there than to "guess" it from a string later. Could some other field in the string contain a date like string for example?

Comment: dates come form input fields. i need to change date format before insert into a mysql server.

Comment: check your string first in $var and update your question to correct

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using strtotime (see http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). You can iterate over the var (explode if you need) and check whether false is returned. Everything else hopefully was a meaningful date/date time and is now a timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

i use this and its work fine. thanks to all.

```
$var = preg_replace("/([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{4})/i","$3-$2-$1",$var);
```